# How to assign a natural number to variable in Coq?

Tags: coq

How can I assign a natural number to a register (a register is represented by natural number).

For example how do I load a natural number n to register k?
How can I compare two natural numbers and assign to a register?

My thinking is to define an inductive type with n, k as natural numbers but I'm not sure what the constructors should be like....

I'm doing something like:

```
Inductive assign (n, k : nat) Type :=
| load k => k
| load k n =>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to represent the state of all registers as a function from the register number to the stored natural number. We can define a register type indexed by natural numbers as follows:

```
Inductive register : Type :=
  R : nat -> register.
```

This is not strictly necessary, but having a separate type for registers prevents confusion between the registers and the natural numbers they store. A state then is just a function from register to nat, and in the empty state we can consider every register to hold the value zero.

```
Definition state := register -> nat.
Definition empty_state : state := fun _ => 0.
```

The assignment operation can now be implemented as a function that takes a state and returns a new state with the specified register taking on a new value. To define this we need to prove a quick theorem establishing that register equality is decidable:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.EqNat.

Theorem eq_register_decide : forall r1 r2 : register, {r1 = r2} + {r1 <> r2}.
Proof.
  intros r1 r2. destruct r1 as [n1]. destruct r2 as [n2].
  destruct (eq_nat_decide n1 n2) as [Heq | Hneq].
  (* Case 1: n1 = n2 *)
    left. replace n2 with n1. reflexivity. apply eq_nat_eq. apply Heq.
  (* Case 2: n1 <> n2 *)
    right. intros contra. inversion contra.
    apply Hneq. apply eq_eq_nat. apply H0.
Qed.

Definition assign (st : state) (k : register) (n : nat) : state :=
  fun k' => if eq_register_decide k k' then n else st k'.
```

Here's an example showing that this works. We can assign the value 5 into register 0 and successfully read it back out again:

```
Example assign_five_to_r0 : (assign empty_state (R 0) 5) (R 0) = 5.
Proof.
  unfold assign. destruct (eq_register_decide (R 0) (R 0)).
  reflexivity. exfalso. apply n. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

This code is inspired by the update function defined in the Imp chapter of [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html) by Pierce et al. There they solve a similar problem but use "variables" instead of "registers."